# Presentation Issue in an Unordered List

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, html-lists

I'm having an issue with correctly presenting items in an unordered list.  The labels are floating left and the related spans that are long in length are wrapping and showing below the label.  I need a solution that keeps the related spans in their respective columns.  In other words, I don't want long spans to show under the labels.  What property can I take advantage of so that I get the desired layout in all of the popular browsers, including IE6?  Thanks in advance for the help.

My code is as follows:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <label>Name</label>
        <span><%= Html.Encode(Model.Name) %></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Entity</label>
        <span><%= Html.Encode(Model.Entity) %></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Phone</label>
        <span><%= Html.Encode(Model.Phone) %></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My CSS styling is as follows:

```
ul
{
    display:block;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

ul li label
{
    float:left;
    width:100px;
}
```

Comment: I'd personally recommend that you use a definition list instead, or maybe even a table for this type of information.

Comment: The `label` tag is not intended for this type of usage. You should really consider using a `dl`.

Comment: Why are label tags not intended for this use?  What are the benefits of using a definition list?  Thanks in advance for the clarification.

Comment: [Label tags are meant to be used in combination with input elements.](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp)

Using a definition list would increase accessibility. Using appropriate markup helps disabled users (screen readers will announce your terms and definitions as such, instead of reading a bunch of seemingly unconnected words).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in Firefox. It should also work in IE6.

```
ul li span {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```